# ef code first mapping one table into some entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I try to solve following:

In the entities **HRCard** and **BPCard** I have properties

```
public int DefaultAddressId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("DefaultAddressId")]
public AddressDetail Address { get; set; } // table AddressDetail
```

so far no problem, now my Problem:
In **BPCard** i have additionally a property:

```
public virtual ICollection<AddressDetail> Addresses { get; set; } //table AddressDetail
```

following the complete Code:

```
public abstract class EntityBase : IEntityModel {
[Key]
public int EntityId { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
public string EntityKey { get; set; }

//...
}

// table HRCards
public class HRCard : EntityBase {
//Id from base class
// working fine
//...

public int DefaultAddressId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("DefaultAddressId")]
public AddressDetail Address { get; set; } // table AddressDetail
}

// table BPCards
public class BPCard : EntityBase {
//Id from base class
// working fine
//...
public int DefaultAddressId { get; set; }
public int DefaultContactId { get; set; }

//working fine
[ForeignKey("DefaultAddressId")]
public AddressDetail DefaultAddress { get; set; } //table AddressDetail

//how can i solve this??
// table AddressDetail
public virtual ICollection<AddressDetail> Addresses { get; set; } 
}

public class AddressDetail : EntityBase {
//Id from base class
// working fine
//...
public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

I have long time searched, but no result solve my problem really. My 1st solution was split the table into HRAddress and BPAddress this is working fine.

Edit:
If I start enable migrations I get an error message:

"The property 'ParentId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type."

many thanks

PS:
can I change the tags later for better mapping?

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem or what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm using Code first and the migration tool is running in an error.

//how can i solve this??
public virtual ICollection<AddressDetail> Addresses { get; set; }

Comment: @FaceOfIngo Which error? Edit it in in your question please

Comment: Still not clear what is the problem. Could you add error text and your desirable result.

Comment: I  have edit my question and added my error.

OK, I'm confused???? Every time the migration tool has thrown the execption. Now it work with my posted code!

I think it was a layer 8 issue on user layer ;)


Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the expected relationship you want with the Address POCO

You can solve the relationship using the annotation with something like

```
public class AddressDetail : EntityBase {
//Id from base class

public virtual ICollection<BPCard> Addresses { get; set; } 
//public virtual BPCard Addresses { get; set; } 
public virtual ICollection<HRCard> Addresses { get; set; } 
//public virtual BPCard Addresses { get; set; } 
}
```

or directly on your model with something like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        //one-to-many
        modelBuilder.Entity<HRCard>()
                    .HasMany<AddressDetails>(s => s.Id)
                    .WithRequired(s => s.HRCard)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.AddressId);
}
```